# transfer list data to another list without getting (collection) C#

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

I am trying to generate 6 random numbers and store them in a list and then display these list items in another list
so far i have

```
        Random random_generator = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        int random_numbers;

        List<int> lst_numbers = new List<int>();

        lst_display.Items.Clear();

        while (lst_numbers.Count < 6)
        {
            random_numbers = random_generator.Next(1,45);
            if (!lst_numbers.Contains(random_numbers))
            {
                lst_numbers.Add(random_numbers);
            }
            else
            {

            }
            lst_display.Items.Add(lst_numbers);
```

though it finishes with (collections) instead of the actual numbers stored

**Here is the final working code**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random_generator = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        int random_numbers;

        List<int> lst_numbers = new List<int>();

        lst_display.Items.Clear();

        while (lst_numbers.Count < 6)
        {
            random_numbers = random_generator.Next(1, 45);
            if (!lst_numbers.Contains(random_numbers))
            {
                lst_numbers.Add(random_numbers);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        lst_display.Items.Add(string.Join(",", lst_numbers));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: why do you not add the number directly to the second list?

Comment: I have to take a list of 6 items and then display them on one line in the new list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line inside your `while` loop (you're missing a closing curly brace) is the culprit:

```
lst_display.Items.Add(lst_numbers);
```

You're adding the entire collection to `lst_display.Items`, and you're doing it once for each iteration.

Either keep that line of code inside the loop, but only add the current randomly generated number:

```
lst_display.Items.Add(random_numbers);
```

Or move it outside the loop, and add the collection once, after the `while` loop is done. The `Items` property is an `ObjectCollection`, so you'll need to cast to an object array if you go this route:

```
while (...)
{
    ...
}
lst_display.Items.AddRange(lst_numbers.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

Unless you're using the `List<int>` later on, you could just remove that code and add the randomly generated numbers directly to `lst_display.Items` using my first example.

---

Update, after seeing your comment:

> "I have to take a list of 6 items and then display them on one line in the new list"

If you want to display them all on a single line in your ListBox, there's a method called [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a collection and flattens it out.

So after your while loop is done, you could call this:

```
lst_display.Items.Add(string.Join(",", lst_numbers));
```

Comment: if i then wanted say 5 lines of 6 random numbers each line how would i go about that?

Answer (score 0):

Does the code below solve your problem? Please let me know. Thanks.

```
            Random random_generator = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

            int random_numbers;

            List<int> lst_numbers = new List<int>();
            List<int> lst_display = new List<int>();

            while (lst_numbers.Count < 6)
            {
                random_numbers = random_generator.Next(1, 45);
                if (!lst_numbers.Contains(random_numbers))
                {
                    lst_numbers.Add(random_numbers);
                }
            };

            lst_display.AddRange(lst_numbers);
```

Comment: seems to accept the code fine but i get no output on my form